# Spark Cassandra Connector in Action:How does it work if Cassandra is hosted on a different server

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Scenario: Cassandra is hosted on a server `a.b.c.d` and spark runs on server say `w.x.y.z`.

Assume i want to transform the data from a table(say table)casssandra and rewrite the same to other table(say tableNew) in cassandra using Spark,The code that i write looks something like this

```scala
val conf = new SparkConf(true)
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "a.b.c.d")
        .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "<UserName>")            
        .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "<Password>")

val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("yarn")
    .config(conf)
    .getOrCreate()

val dfFromCassandra = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(Map( "table" -> "<table>", "keyspace" -> "<Keyspace>")).load()

val filteredDF = dfFromCassandra.filter(filterCriteria).write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(Map( "table" -> "<tableNew>", "keyspace" -> "<Keyspace>")).save
```

Here `filterCriteria` represents the transformation/filtering that I do. Iam not sure how Spark cassandra connector works in this case internally.
This is the Confusion that I have:

1: Does spark load the data from Cassandra source table  to the memory and then filter the same and reload the same to the Target table Or

2: Does Spark cassandra connector convert the filter criteria to `Where` clause and loads only the relevant data to form RDD and writes the same back to target table in Cassandra Or

3:Does the entire operation happens as a cql operation where the query is converted to sqllike query and is executed in cassandra itself?(I am almost sure that this is not what happens)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is either 1. or 2. depending on your `filterCriteria`. Naturally Spark itself can't do any CQL filtering but custom datasources can implement it using predicate pushdown. In case if Cassandra driver, it is implemented [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/v2.4.0/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/cassandra/CassandraSourceRelation.scala#L142) and the answer depends if that covers the used `filterCriteria`.